# Compiling Fortran Code on OSX for Windows 64

Tags: compilation, fortran, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile some Fortran files into a Windows 64-bit executable on a Mac with macOS Sierra. I have already succesfully compiled the Fortran code to run on OSX with GFortran, but now also want to do it for a computer running Windows 64-bit.

I am really not very familiar with compilers, so am finding the documentation out there quite confusing. I understand that some cross-compilers exist and that MinGW could possibly help me achieve my goal.

Any advice on specifically how I should go about this and whether it is even possible would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Well, yes there are cross-compilers out there, but typically for a different CPU, not OS. Even if for different OS, Windows is way too different from everything else. I seriously doubt anything like that exists, because people who need compiling for Windows just get Windows. Why can't you just install Windows in a virtual machine? It will be much easier.

Comment: cygwin calls mingw a cross compiler (but it's not cross-hardware).  If you wish to rebuild your program on a Win64 platform, cygwin64 might be one of the better choices.  Another might be Win10 WSL (but I find it one of the less reliable Windows development environments).  You seem unsure of what you want and unwilling to say enough for us to state an opinion.